# Redirect stdin to stdout

Tags: c, stdout, stdin

Let's say I have a trivial C program that adds 2 numbers together:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a, b;
    printf("Enter a: "); scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Enter b: "); scanf("%d", &b);

    printf("a + b = %d\n", a + b);
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of typing into the termnial every time it executes, I enter the values of `a` and `b` into a file:

```
// input.txt
10
20
```

I then redirect `stdin` to this file:

```
./a.out < input.txt
```

The program works but its output is a bit messed up:

```
Enter a: Enter b: a + b = 30
```

Is there a way to redirect stdin to stdout so the output appears as if a user typed the values manually, ie:

```
Enter a: 10
Enter b: 20
a + b = 30
```

Comment: There's no portable way to do it, but on POSIX systems, you could check `isatty(0)` (from `unistd.h`), and if stdin is not a tty, echo back a line after reading it.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without touching the code?

Comment: Not without modifying the code, no.

Comment: yes, there are ways, but all of them require more code :D for example on Linux you could use a wrapper program that debugs the program using `ptrace` and intercepts all `read` system calls... now, perhaps modifying the source would still be easier...

Comment: The real problem is that the output of `input.txt` has to come in exact places, after `Enter a:` there has to be a `10`. Cause you can `tee /dev/stderr <input.txt | a.out` but then `10` and `20` will be unsynchronized with the output of your program. So the only way is to synchronize input with output of your program - which suggest you have to track internal state of your program - either by tracking `read` system calls within your program, or writing another program that will capturing output like `expect` and act accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use expect for this. Expect is a tool for automating interactive command-line programs. Here's how you could automate typing those values in:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 20

spawn "./a.out"

expect "Enter a: " { send "10\r" }
expect "Enter b: " { send "20\r" }

interact
```

This produces output like this:

```
$ ./expect     
spawn ./test
Enter a: 10
Enter b: 20
a + b = 30
```

There are more examples [here](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/).

Answer (score 0):

Forget prompting; try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int a, b;
    if (scanf("%d%d", &a, &b) != 2) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, a + b);
    return 0;
}
```

You may want to find a way to allow your users to know what the executable is about, maybe adding command-line options?

```
$ echo "10 20" |./a.out
10 + 20 = 30

$ ./a.out --help
Program reads two integers and displays their sum

$
```